# How to DSP filter a signal that has a variable time base?

Tags: microcontroller, dsp, digital-filter

I am measuring frequency on a microcontroller by measuring the time between pulses on an input.

DSP filter theory requires the time base of an input signal to be regular, e.g. IIR and FIR filters. But the time base of this is by its nature irregular (if I have a 1kHz signal, I get 1k data points a second, if I am running at 20Hz, I get 20 data points per second). I have considered several non linear methods where depending on the frequency, the filtering technique changes, but I'm not in love with this idea. Is there a family of filter algorithms to solve this kind of problem? If so, what are they called?

Comment: I don't understand why it is "irregular". If it is 1kHz, it is always 1kHz. If it is 20Hz, it is always 20Hz. It is not changing in the runtime.

Comment: Assume an incoming signal with noise, so a 1kHz signal with noise, changing in run time, hence requiring a filter to get a more averaged reading.

Comment: I think you are confusing the sampling rate with the actual signal frequencies.

Comment: That's the problem: for e.g. an IIR you have a sampling frequency, and all of the theory and well established filters that go with that. 
For this problem, there is no sampling frequency, just time differences.

Comment: Wait. So your signal is actually a series of time intervals? Well, that's not enough information to conclude what you are trying to do. So... What are you trying to do?

Comment: I do not understand why you are trying to use an IIR filter to calculate signal frequency from pulses. Can you explain your rationle

Comment: I'm trying to measure frequency, but I need to filter the input. I'm asking if there is a family of filters used for this type of application, since I am only familiar with DSP's that are based on a sampling frequency. For instance, I could use a rolling average, but the problem is that as the frequency slows down, the filter characteristics drastically change. I could see how many pulses I get per time period and use e.g. an IIR low pass filter, but my input frequency can be extremely low where you would have 0 counts as the input many times, then one, then a bunch of zeros, then one...

Comment: @Kvegaroro, I'm not trying to use IIR. I'm trying to find a family of filters that would be suitable for this application. I'm specifically saying that IIR filters are not suitable for what I need.

Comment: @Bob You will get the delay in the measurement regardless of the filter. Filters are not magic. If there is a long time between the two pulses, no way you can know this time before the second pulse arrives.

Comment: @Eugene Sh, I am not looking for magic, just a reference to a family of filters suitable for this application. Many people measure frequencies, so I would assume someone has developed a family of filters for this kind of signal. I am assuming it will end up having some non-linearity to it (if not, I will need to put some in regardless to hit my output update spec), but I'm looking to start at a point with some rigor. I have some ideas, but I need to get this right and I haven't found anything. That's why I put it out to the community.

Comment: If you're just looking for frequency, try a Schmitt trigger type input - you're looking for zero crossings, but move the threshold so that noise around zero doesn't show up as a spurious zero crossing.

Comment: @pjc50, I'm using a timer module on a microcontroller. Assume a noise free signal for now, since I can check for periods that are too short and therefore noise. I'm looking for what family of filters to go with; there must be something, right?

Comment: If it's a noise free signal, *what is the filter for*?

Comment: @pjc50, I'm sorry, I said that stupidly. I meant there are no glitches on the signal, no altogether erroneous signals; the noise is in the time of the rising edge. So a Schmitt trigger doesn't help because I'm already measuring a squar-ish wave, not an AC signal with a zero crossing. My apologies for the confusing/incorrect use of "noise free".

Comment: You can still use regular IIR or FIR. It's just your signal uses a constant spacial frequency instead of time frequency. You can use  interpolation to convert it to a constant time base.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what each input pulse means. It's once cycle of your input waveform. But not only that, it's **all** the information you have available.

Create a regular clock, a regular sampling pulse in your DSP to run your filter. This must be faster than the highest frequency you sample. If 1kHz is the highest frequency you measure, then 2kHz would be a reasonable sampling rate.

At each sampling interval, you have either had a cycle of input, so the frequency for that interval is 1, that's one cycle per interval, or you have not, so a frequency of zero.

For instance if you had a 500Hz input signal with a 2kHz internal sampling clock, your data would look like 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0...

The density of 1s *is* the frequency, but it's very noisy at the moment and needs to be low pass filtered. Once you have lowpass filtered this sufficiently well, you would get 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, which indictates your input frequency is 0.25 of your sampling rate.

As you will need a relatively long time constant, an IIR filter would seem to be a good bet. You could also try a CIC (Hogenhaur) filter if you wanted to use a recursively implemented FIR.

As you have used all the information in the input signal, **this is as good as it gets** with a linear filter. All you can do is switch between a very low frequency filter with long delay, or a wider band filter with less delay.

However, you might be able to improve things subjectively a little with a non-linear pre-processing stage before your low pass filter.

You could do a first order hold on the edge data. Instead of shifting 1s and 0s into your filter, you could shift in 1/Ns, where N is the number of sampling pulses that have elapsed since the last input edge. This will introduce a frequency response, but I suspect that it will not matter in your crude application.

For instance, if the frequency was 1kHz and then suddenly changed to 500Hz, the input to your filter would be 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25. Notice that two cycles of 0.5 and four cycles of 0.25 both sum to 1 input clock edge. Now the filter is starting with a 'nicer' signal.

This method could produce quite serious errors if the frequency suddenly changes downwards. For instance after two pulses separated by 1mS, so outputting 0.5 into the filter, the next pulse takes 1 second to arrive. For the whole of that second, the frequency estimate is too high. This could be mitigated by a) once you have outputted a complete cycle's worth of frequency data and the next pulse has not arrived, switch to outputting zero or b) once the delay exceeds 1/the_output, switch to outputting 1/delay since last pulse. This is not correct either, but has less latency than not doing it, and is smoother than (a).

It depends what qualities you want in your final filtered output, do you want it to look pretty, or do you want it to be 'correct' in some signal processing sense. You can't magically create information out of nothing, and your pulse arrivals have severely limited the information available to you. You can only do with this data the best you can.

Comment: I had considered the 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0... type signal as the input, then just use a low pass IIR filter, so this sort of confirms my suspicions. The problem is my spec is from 1/4Hz to 5kHz. Obviously, to have a fast response for a sudden stop I would need some non-linear magic in the code. But for changing frequencies I would either end up with too much ripple current or far too slow of a response. I have considered using multiple ranges of continuously running IIR's, where when one goes out of range it moves to another, where the response rate is better suited. Is that a crazy design?

Comment: so have you considered the first order hold in my last two paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

You're sampling a series of time periods, then computing frequency as 1/period. How about taking a moving, possibly weighted, average of the last N time periods and then computing 1/average?

This has the advantage of not embedding any assumptions about the underlying frequency and is also easy to compute. It still has the disadvantage of "lagging" the input. To get round that I think you have to introduce "virtual" samples: a timer saying "I expected a pulse by now but haven't got one, what would the frequency be if I did recieve a pulse now?"